# Отображение документа без возможности копирования текста

Tags: java, spring, angular

Добрый день я делаю сайт для продажи студенческих работ использую Angular 9,Spring, Java. Мне нужно чтобы перед тем как купить работу пользователь мог предварительно просмотреть её без возможности копирования текста.
В интернете я нашёл такой вариант:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://writing.engr.psu.edu/workbooks/formal_report_template.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Вопрос:

1. не забанит ли меня гугл учитывая что посетителей может быть несколько сотен или тысяч ?
2. здесь указан доступ по url  к документу, можно ли будет так отобразить файл который лежит на сервере по такому адресу: С:\files\1.docx ?

Answer (score 1):

Бесполезная затея.

1. В каком месте это *"без возможности копирования текста"*?
2. А если он просто откроет ссылку, которую ты передаёшь гуглу как параметр?

> А как тогда на других сайтах реализован предварительный просмотр текста ?

- Число доступных страниц ограничивают.
- Делают всё картинками, но картинки тоже распознать можно.
- Гуглокниги вроде считают количество просмотренных страниц.

Answer (score 0):

1. не забанит ли меня гугл учитывая что посетителей может быть несколько сотен или тысяч ? - нет если основание только число посетителей.
2. здесь указан доступ по url к документу, можно ли будет так отобразить файл который лежит на сервере по такому адресу: С:\files\1.docx ? - На Самом деле вы указываете не сам файл а ссылку на него, а вот Label ссылки это ваше сугубо личное мнение как назвать.